# Can someone explain to me where does ''None'' come from?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def test(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)

print test("Hello", "World")
```

now when I run the code I get the following output:

```
arg1: 'Hello', arg2: 'World'
None
```

Answer (score 3):

You call `test` (which prints the arguments (the first line of output)) **then** you pass its return value to `print`.

It doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None` (which gets printed as the second line of output).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning nothing so `None` is returned by default.

```
def test(arg1, arg2):
    #print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)
    return "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)

print test("Hello", "World")
```

Above code will print value via return statement.